# SQL: How to get all descendants from a table with "many-to-many" related columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many, recursive-query

I am still exploring SQL, hence I have an apparently easy question.
I have the following table in SQL Server 2008 R2.
As you see, this is a mapping table where there is a "many-to-many" relation between InstrumentIDs and ProductIDs:

```
|InstrumentID | ProductID   |ID(PK)|
|-------------|-------------|------|
|10           |21           |0     |
|10           |22           |1     |
|11           |22           |2     |
|11           |23           |3     |
|12           |24           |4     |
|12           |25           |5     |
|----------------------------------|
```

I wish to write a query/SP which takes as an input let's say an InstrumentID and returns all the associated mappings extracted recursively.
For example, let's say that I provide InstrumentID = 10. Then, a satisfying result would be:

```
|InstrumentID | ProductID   |ID(PK)|
|-------------|-------------|------|
|10           |21           |0     |
|10           |22           |1     |
|11           |22           |2     |
|11           |23           |3     |
|----------------------------------|
```

What is the best way of accomplishing this ?
An example would definitely be useful.

I have tried the following query using CTE:

```
WITH Map
AS ( 
    -- Anchor
    SELECT InstrumentID, ProductID
    FROM InstrumentProduct
    WHERE InstrumentID IN (10)
    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive
    SELECT IP.InstrumentID, IP.ProductID
    FROM InstrumentProduct IP
    INNER JOIN Map 
        ON IP.InstrumentID = Map.InstrumentID 
        OR IP.ProductID = Map.ProductID
)
SELECT *
FROM Map
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 50);
```

But query is executed with an error: *"The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 5 has been exhausted before statement completion."* 
However the results are returned apparently correct, but duplicated.

Any kind of help and advice is definitely helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand clearly what is the relation for parent-child in your case. For me, given `InstrumentID = 10` should return every row in the sample data

Comment: Increase your MAXRECURSION count

Comment: @Pradeep Please, don't just blindly give advice about just increasing `MAXRECURSION` without fully understanding the issue, the query could be going on circles

Comment: @Lamak - Indeed the example was confusing. I have edited the initial table and the expected results in case of InstrumentID = 10.

So, unfortunately there is no parent-child relation. An Instrument can reference one or many Products, but also a Product can reference one or many Instruments.

Comment: If 11 had product id 24 in the second 11-row, then it would mean the whole table gets returned.

Comment: @EMS That is correct! That is the kind of relation which leads to the expected result.